# Errors making a new date field conditional on other date field

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to make new date field based on two other columns.  If 'R' is present in the Indicator column, I want the date to be the ReportDate.  If 'R' is not present, I want the date to be IncidentDate.  A working example:

```
IncidentDate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
ReportDate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-5-25','2007-5-14'))
Indicator <- c('','R','')

incident_data <- data.frame(IncidentDate, ReportDate, Indicator)

typeof(IncidentDate) #double


incident_data$calculatedDate <- ifelse(incident_data$ReportDate=='R',as.Date(incident_data$ReportDate), as.Date(incident_data$IncidentDate))
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I've also tried:

```
incident_data$calculatedDate <- ifelse(incident_data$ReportDate=='R',as.Date(as.character(incident_data$ReportDate)), as.Date(as.character(incident_data$IncidentDate)))
```

Which gives me the same error. Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, it may be better to use assignment on a logical vector instead of `ifelse` for `Date` class as `ifelse` can coerce and remove the `Date` attribute.

```
i1 <- incident_data$Indicator=='R'
incident_data$calculatedDate <- incident_data$IncidentDate
incident_data$calculatedDate[i1] <- incident_data$ReportDate
```

---

The logical should be based on the `Indicator` column.  However, `ifelse` coerces the `Date` to its integer storage mode.  So, it may be better to use `if_else` or `case_when`.  With `if_else`, `case_when`, there is a type check associated with the the `true`, `false` cases.

```
library(dplyr)
if_else(incident_data$Indicator=='R',as.Date(incident_data$ReportDate), 
     as.Date(incident_data$IncidentDate))
#[1] "2010-11-01" "2008-05-25" "2007-03-14"
```

Comment: you're the man akrun.  But, can you explain why if_else works, and ifelse doesn't?  Is the only difference that ifelse is attempting to coerce into an integer, but if_else doesn't?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 It is one of the feature of source code in `ifelse` that doesn't allow or strip off the attributes.